# js/jquery - How to change existing iframe attribute from inside the iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, tfs

I am working with TFS and I'm trying to upload an extension(web page) to the dashboard.
When the dashboard loads my extension it wrapps my it with Iframe.

[TFS Iframe example](https://keesverhaar.files.wordpress.com/2016/03/image3.png)

The iframe sandbox attribute missing the **allow-same-origin** which allow me to manipulate the page that contains my extension.
Is there a way to change the iframe attribute from my extension web page? 
the whole page looks like:

```
<html> // Tfs page
<body>
<div> // main page
    <iframe sandbox='allow-scripts ...'> // the iframe that wrapps my extension, missing 'allow-same-origin'
        <html> // my extension
        <body>
        ...
        </body>
        </html>
    </iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks...

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. I wanted to add a new hub (project) which embeds an external website. Did you solved it somehow?

Comment: No. It's impossible.

Comment: [Here is a link to the msdn forum in which I asked the same question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/66a1a13d-59a2-4b52-9c03-4df2bd7792ac/change-iframe-sandbox-attribute-after-uploading-an-extension?forum=tfsgeneral) @Andreas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is on purpose: you should use the SDK to interact with VSTS/TFS, otherwise it is easy to imagine a rogue Extension that sells a company's Intellectual Property in the deep web.